# Кнопка наверх JS - работает в Mozilla, в Chrome глючит

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Есть сайт. Решил сделать кнопку наверх с помощью JS. В Mozilla кнопка отрабатывает толково: появляется при смещении вниз, кликабельна и плавно скроллит наверх.

В Хроме проблемы после нажатия: движение явно очень замедленно, поднимается максимум на высоту одного экрана и останавливается. Повторный клик приводит к "дерганию" стриницы, после обновления - также смещается на высоту одного экрана.

Подскажите, что не так?

```
(function() {
'use strict';

function trackScroll() {
    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
    var coords = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    if (scrolled > coords) {
        goTopBtn.classList.add('back_to_top-show');
    }
    if (scrolled < coords) {
        goTopBtn.classList.remove('back_to_top-show');
    }
}

function backToTop() {
    var scrollStep = window.pageYOffset / 40;
    if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
        window.scrollBy(0, -(scrollStep));
        setTimeout(backToTop, 20);
    }
 }

var goTopBtn = document.querySelector('.back_to_top');

window.addEventListener('scroll', trackScroll);
 goTopBtn.addEventListener('click', backToTop);
```

```
})();
let html = document.documentElement;


let scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;

html.style.top = -scrollPosition + "px";
html.classList.add("hystmodal__opened");

html.classList.remove("hystmodal__opened");

window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
html.style.top = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Заменил участок кода с функцией со ScroolBy -> на ScroolTo (0,0). И убрал планировщик SetTimeOut. Работает и без него с плавной прокруткой. Проверял в Chrome, Mozilla, Edge.

```
function backToTop() {
   if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}
```